# Ambiguous (and maybe euphemistic) word or phrase for romantic partner

Tags: phrase-requests

What is an ambiguous word for a romantic partner, which doesn't make it *crystal* clear that they are in fact a romantic partner rather than just a friend? A euphemism might be a rough approximation of this, although of course it doesn't quite fit the bill, and some are not ambiguous at all.

Genderless and gendered answers are both interesting, though I'm personally interested in one which could apply to a girlfriend.

Ideally it'd be something which leaves the possibility that it's a romantic partner open, perhaps quite strongly so. 'Friend' suffers in this respect, as it's often used to make clear that someone is "just a friend", and people have suggested to me that girlfriends or boyfriends might be offended by it.

Anyone familiar with British culture or certain subsets thereof would understand why all this is vitally important ;)

Comment: Ever heard of the Ummer? "Mum and dad, I'd like you to meet my um..., er......"

Comment: I can't back it up with links which seems to be a requirement here and don't know how it'll fly in British, but how about "companion"?  It can connote a "special friend" (or the word "girlfriend/boyfriend" for people in their 40+s), or (just) a dinner or travel companion; more familiar than an acquaintance.

Comment: I don't understand the need to be ambiguous. If you need to protect your girlfriend, then introduce her as your *close friend*, or "someone I've been going out with." If you are both single, what is the problem? Just call her your "girlfriend". I'm very familiar with British culture, people tend to be quite open about these matters, unless they are embarrassed. Is it a huge age difference? She's still your girlfriend! People will suss things out in the end, so you might as well be forthright.

Comment: It's going to be either ambiguous or euphemistic, but not both.

Comment: You realize, of course, that the more ambiguous you are, the more it piques the curiosity of the listener, and the more they will be inclined to pry.

Comment: @user662852 Companion is probably the best suggestion so far, as the answers below don't really fit - you should write it in as one!

Comment: @Mari-LouA the reference to British culture is tongue in cheek, though not wholly - certain subsets I partly fit in tend not to be open to an extent which elicits comment from foreigners! 

But I'm sure everyone can imagine that there are *some* circumstances in which you don't want to shout about a new relationship from the rooftops to everyone - exes, parents, certain friendship groups, etc. (In my particular case this isn't about an introduction, but a reply to a Facebook comment which others will see, before the milestone of official Facebook relationship-setting.)

Comment: @TimRomano, So is the word "a ffable" ambiguous or euphemistic or both?

Comment: @tog22, Instead of using "friend" which suggests "just a friend", you can instead [opt for equivocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumlocution#Equivocation) to keep the possibility open.

Comment: @Pacerier: or neither.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comments above, [companion](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/companion)

This can be a romantic companion, a dinner companion, or a travel companion.  It's from the same Latin roots as "company", *com panis*, "with bread", so at root it's someone with whom you share meals.  It's also a term used by couples that feel too aged to be comfortable with boy/girlfriend, and we know from the historical record that [the Beasties are always out looking for a female companion](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/beastieboys/heyladies.html)

Answer (score 2):

For use on an ad hoc basis in some situations:

**She's only his *plus one* tonight.  I'm not sure they're seeing each other.**

Answer (score 1):

I think you could get away with using *partner in crime* in a joking manner. It is using "partner" in a manner that would be considered playful if, in fact, the referent considers the relationship romantic. At the same time, someone outside the relationship could only guess apart from non-verbal communication. ("A wink is as good as a nudge.")

Answer (score 0):

How about **Person Of Interest**?

This could be a playful and vague way to describe someone that you are romantically interested in. [In the US, the police use this term to describe someone involved or connected to a criminal investigation, but there is not yet enough evidence to arrest them.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Person_of_interest)

You could keep the legal metaphor running thusly:

"Hey, who's that guy you came here with? Is he your boyfriend?"

"John? He's a person of interest. We had some fun last weekend, but the jury's still out."

Comment: Hi, selovich, and welcome to English Language & Usage. Although phrase requests and single-word requests do lend themselves to brief answers, this site much prefers answers that include a (brief) discussion of why the suggested phrase or word is suitable for the specific context that the questioner is identifies. In particular, adding a relevant definition from a reference work is an easy way to help establish the aptness of a suggested phrase or word. Please consider adding some corroborating information to your answer. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Sven! I hope my elaboration is helpful!

Comment: +1 for supplementing your original answer with the additional explanation and examples. It's much more of a self-contained answer now, I think, though it would still benefit from a link to an authoritative dictionary definition of "person of interest."

Answer (score 0):

I think **friend** or **good friend** fit the bill if ambiguous is what you are going for.

> I spent the weekend away with a friend of mine.
>
> I spent the weekend away with a good friend of mine.

Are they lovers? Or just friends? It's not clear; it kind of hints at that, but there's plausible deniability.

Less ambiguously, you have **lady friend** or **guy friend**.

> I have a lady friend coming around for dinner tonight.

Lady friend especially, is a straight up euphemism for someone you have some kind of sexual/romantic relationship with.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I might phrase a new but *deepening* relationship, without denying you are both romantically involved.

- She/he is somebody who(m) I get along with.
- [First name] is a person whose company I enjoy immensely.
- [First name] is a close/dear friend of mine.
- She/he is someone I (deeply) care about.

Answer (score -1):

How about **[playmate](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/playmate)**? (Oxford)

> *Used euphemistically to refer to a person’s lover*

Just the right amount of naughty ;)

---

EDIT: For maintaining ambiguity, people go with "**[special friend](https://www.google.com/search?q=madame%20and%20her%20special%20friend&oq=madame%20and%20her%20special%20friend&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#)**".

But I'm sure there's something better out there

Comment: Ha, fun, but far from ambiguous!

Comment: @tog22: See edit. I tried to find the clip from Two and a Half Men when the waiter calls Alan the 'special friend' of Norma, but I couldn't. The way he said it... it would have made my point.

Comment: @TusharRaj In my experience, *special friend* drips with as much innuendo as *playmate* does. It's not ambiguous. You're saying this is a person you have a primarily sexual relationship with.

Comment: @DanBron: I always thought people used it to refer to other couples when they were nearly sure, but not beyond reasonable doubt. So I always sensed a little ambiguity.

Comment: @TusharRaj You're right there's a distinction between other people calling X your "special friend" and you introducing her/him that way. But even in the case of a third party applying the appellation ... certain (strong) insinuations are being made. The only other time I've seen it used is as a direct euphemism for girlfriend/boyfriend among elderly people (eg a widow newly dating a widower) who feel "girl"friend and "boy"friend are inapplicable or just juvenile.

Comment: @DanBron: The strong insinuations are exactly what the OP wants; that's why this phrase came to mind.

Comment: @TusharRaj No, understood, understood. What I was trying to say is "strong insinuation" only applies if it's a third party describing your partner (to a fourth party). Typically out of earshot of you. If you introduce someone as your "special friend" you're essentially saying they are -- excuse the crude language here, but it's the only way to clearly make the point -- your fuck buddy.

Comment: @DanBron: I didn't realize the OP wanted the term to apply to their partner. I thought they were looking for a term to describe other couples. My bad. You think I should revert?

Comment: @TusharRaj I think your answer is fine as an answer. I don't think it will ultimately prevail, but I don't think uou need to change/revert or delete it, either.

Comment: @DanBron: I hope it doesn't prevail. That's why I said there must be something better out there. Even I'm curious!

Comment: @DanBron: The `(or Euphemistic)` threw me off. That's why I answered. Edited the title.

Comment: Good edit. I seriously appreciate your sincere engagement with this site, and conscientious responses to feedback. Seriously.

Comment: What about "mate" instead of playmate?

Comment: Yeah, that's an improvement to my title. I do indeed want an ambiguous term to apply to denote my girlfriend, which can have a light coating of insinuation but not absolutely drip with it. "Fuck buddy" definitely isn't what I'm going for ;)